# issue in forming list of tags in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am executing a `python` script through `subprocess` and passing it a named argument. In the `subprocess` script I then have to form a `list of tags` (`list of key and value pair`) whose format is shown below:

```
Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ]
```

Here is my **parent script**:

```
def call_script(tags):

    result = subprocess.Popen(["python","second_script.py","--tags",tags])
    result.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':

tags = '{'
   tags = tags + '"Name":"' + username + '"'
   tags = tags + ', "Designation":"' + Designation + '"'
   tags = tags + ', "Type":"' + type + '"'
   tags = tags + '}'
   tags = str(tags)

   call_script(tags)
```

Here is my **second_script.py**:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Initialize tags
    tags = {}
    lst = []

    # Basic command line argument parsing to launch using boto
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('--tags', type=json.loads)

    args = parser.parse_args()


    print args.tags

    # Build a list of tags
    for k, v in args.tags.iteritems():
        print k
        print v
        tags['Key'] = k
        tags['Value'] = v
        print tags
        lst.append(tags)

    # print 'Tags: ',tags
    print "List of Tags: ",lst
```

When I run this I see only last key-value pair in both `tags` as well as `lst`. How can I form a list of key value pair as I have shown in desired format above?

A sample input could be:

```
Name: Jason
Designation: Analyst
Type: Permanent
```

As such the desired output format should be:

```
Tags = [
{
                'Key': 'Name',
                'Value': 'Jason'
            },
{
                'Key': 'Designation',
                'Value': 'Analyst'
            },
{
                'Key': 'Type',
                'Value': 'Permanent'
            },
]
```

The output of `tags` that I get in my above code is - `{'Value': u'Permanent', 'Key': u'Type'}` while `lst` is: `[{'Value': u'Permanent', 'Key': u'Type'}, {'Value': u'Permanent', 'Key': u'Type'}, {'Value': u'Permanent', 'Key': u'Type'}]`

What mistake am In making in my code and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting `tags` in your for loop:

```
for k, v in args.tags.iteritems():
    tags={} #changed Line
    print k
    print v
    tags['Key'] = k
    tags['Value'] = v
    print tags
    lst.append(tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `dict` is mutable and you are appending references to the same object to `lst`. Replace

```
tags['Key'] = k
tags['Value'] = v
print tags
lst.append(tags)
```

with

```
print tags
lst.append({'Key' : k, 'Value' : v})
```

Comment: I am able to form the list as you mentioned but actually I am trying to use this list in aws run_job_flow() as shown at https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow and it is throwing error. I am trying to pass it to `Tags`.

Comment: `botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Tags[0], value: type: <type 'list'>, valid types: <type 'dict'>`

Comment: I think it(`lst`) has to be dictionary while i am passing a list

Comment: The docs say that `Tags` should be a `list` of `dict`s. In your case, `Tag[0]` seems to be a list, so `Tags` is a `list` of `list`s. Did you wrap it in another `list` constructor?

Comment: No I didn't wrap it in a list construtor. I have lst = [] at the begining

Comment: How can I form a `list` of `dicts` from the arguments that I am passing?

Comment: It is hard for me to tell as you are are passing data as strings. Any reason why you would not wrap second script in a function, and import that function into script #1?

Comment: second script is a standalone script that needs to be called from parent script. Its a structural restriction for me. Since these tags have to be together thats why I am passing them a string

Comment: I would suggest one of the following: either create a third script, where you define a function as in #2; then import that script into both 1 and 2, keeping your structure. Or use `json.loads` and `json.dumps` for parsing the `Tags`.